# MySQL - Convert Date Column to Timestamp

Tags: mysql

I am currently running a website where all logins are tracked inside my database. The column is called "logontime" and has the following form: 2010-06-14 13:36:39

Now I would like to convert those entries to a timestamp format! Is there a MySQL query available that will convert all entries with the above form to timestamps at once?

I am not a SQL guru so there may is a query but I do not know how to achieve that. Would be really great if someone can help me!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Is your current logontime type a datetime?

Comment: No ;(! It is a VARCHAR(20) right now!

Comment: But if it is well formatted like your example it should be possible to change it to DATETIME just by changing the column type or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to modify the column type with:

```
alter table table modify column logontime timestamp;
```

It should convert any existing valid string representation of a timestamp to a `timestamp` value. Nonconvertible values will result in `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Be sure to back up your data before attempting.